# How does pytest do test selection?

Tags: pytest, discovery

I am trying to figure out the expression syntax for py.test selection using the '-k' option.

I have seen the examples, but I am unclear of what the syntax options are when using the 'k' tag.

I am trying to scan the py.test source code, but so far no luck.

Can anyone give me pointers on what the syntax is for py.test test selection (-k)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm.. it's not well documented mainly because it's a bit confused and not that well defined. You can use 'and', 'or' and 'not' to match strings in a test name and/or its markers. [At heart](https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/src/f7f076b07d105d2fceeb38c998910be33f9fe290/_pytest/mark.py?at=default#cl-121), it's an `eval`.

For the moment (until the syntax is hopefully improved) my advice is to:

- Use `--collectonly` to confirm that your `-k` selects what you want before executing tests
- Add [markers](http://pytest.org/latest/mark.html#mark) to tests as needed to further distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I came to understand.  It would be nice if we could send in a regex, or just stupid wildcards.